# How do I configure my Express server to render all of my content, not just my HTML file?

Tags: javascript, express, server, filepath

I'm attempting to build a server for my current project but I'm new to Express. My file directory looks like this:

```
root-directory
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   └── styles.css
│   ├── images
│   │   └── img1.png
|   |   └── img2.png
|   |   └── img3.png
│   └── index.html
|   └── main.js
└── server
    └── app.js
```

This is the code I am using in my server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'))
});

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}.`))
```

Currently, the server is only displaying my static HTML file, and none of the JavaScript or CSS that is linked to it. I have attempted altering my sendFile function to look like this: `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public'))`; but that results in an `Error: Cannot GET /`.

How can I reconfigure my server to display my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript all at once?

Comment: Remove the get handler and replace the static handler with ```app.use('*', express.static('public'));```

Comment: Do you mean like this? 

`const app = express();
app.use('*', express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());

// Commented out below code
// app.get('*', (req, res) => {
//   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'))
// });`

Unfortunately I'm receiving another `Cannot GET /` error now.

Answer (score 2):

- Firstly, you can remove this block:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'))
});
```

You don't need to respond to **all** GET requests (because of the use of '*') with the `index.html` file. Moreover, it conflict with the line `app.use('/static', express.static('public'));`.

- Secondly, you need to replace `/static` in this line with `/`

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
```

Then your app will find `index.html` in the `public` folder to respond to the GET '/' request.

- Thirdly, you need to check your `index.html` file if the link to CSS/JS/image files is valid. For example, the link to `style.css` file should be: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">`.